# Consistent tick label height in BarChart

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, visualization

Consider the following `BarChart` example:

```
m = Superscript["FOO", "m"];
t = Superscript["FOO", "t"];

BarChart[
 {2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1},
 ChartLabels -> {m, t, m, t, m, t}
]
```

[image]

Notice that the labels are staggered: the `t` ones are taller than the `m` ones

**Question:** How do I make all these labels the same height?

---

Things I tried that did not work:

- Map `Framed[#, ContentPadding -> True]&` on the labels
- Map `Style[#, LineSpacing -> {0, 30, 3}]` on the labels (i.e. try to use a fixed line height), in conjunction with the `Framed`

---

**Update:** I found a solution, but it is not very nice, and it does not generalize to labels which are not `Superscript`.

```
fr = Framed[#, ContentPadding -> True, FrameMargins -> None, FrameStyle -> None] &;

m = Superscript["FOO", fr@"m"]
t = Superscript["FOO", fr@"t"]
```

Therefore I am still looking for solutions, ideally something that works for all kinds of labels.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
m = Superscript["FOO", "m"];
t = Style[Superscript["FOO", "t"], ScriptBaselineShifts -> {Automatic, .4}];
BarChart[{2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}, ChartLabels -> {m, t, m, t, m, t}]
```

[image: chart]

Comment: Thank you, I like this much better than my solution with `Framed`!

Comment: Unfortunately, the superscript needs to be pushed down by an extreme amount with the font I am using. I am using Trebuchet MS because it gives me an excellent distinguishability of `I`, `1`, and `l`.

Answer (score 9):

You could place an invisible "t" to the right of the "m":

```
m = Superscript["FOO", Row[{"m", Invisible["t"]}]];
t = Superscript["FOO", "t"];
BarChart[{2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}, ChartLabels -> {m, t, m, t, m, t}]
```

[image: bar graph]

---

You can rotate the labels:

```
m = Rotate[Superscript["FOO", Row[{"m", Invisible["t"]}]], -90 Degree];
t = Rotate[Superscript["FOO", "t"], -90 Degree];
BarChart[{2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}, ChartLabels -> {m, t, m, t, m, t}]
```

[image: rotate]

Comment: This is a good solution too! One disadvantage is that if I rotate the labels by 90 degrees, then I get the undesired staggered look again. I need to use rotated labels on the smaller versions of the plot.

Comment: You can rotate labels by -90 degrees.  E.g.

m = Rotate[Superscript["FOO", Row[{"m", Invisible["t"]}]], -90 Degree];
t = Rotate[Superscript["FOO", "t"], -90 Degree];
BarChart[{2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}, ChartLabels -> {m, t, m, t, m, t}]